# React native useState hook not updating state with async call using axios in custom hook

Tags: react-native, axios, use-state

I have a created a custom hook to make an async call to a rest api that returns an array of objects. I have two async methods. First method returns a list of objects. On a successful rest call the state array [dataEntry] gets updated but on the second call which a post request returns a single object. When I try to add the newly returned object to the state array [dataEntry] I am unable to see the new object added to the array.

```
import { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import restApi from '../api/restApi';
import { Context as AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext';


export default () => {
    const { state } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [lastPage, setLastPage] = useState(true);
    const [nextPageNumber, setNextPageNumber] = useState(0);
    const [dataEntry, setDataEntry] = useState([]);
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(null);
    const [dataUpdate, setDataUpdate] = useState(false);


    const getAllData = async (pageNumber, pageSize) => {
        try {
            restApi.get('/data/list', {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + state.tokenData,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response.data.result);
                setLastPage(response.data.lastPage);
                setNextPageNumber(response.data.nextPageNumber);
                setDataEntry([...response.data.result]);
                setDataUpdate(true);
            })


        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.response.data);
        }
    }

    const createData = async ({ dataName }) => {
        try {
            console.log('creating data ' + dataName);
            restApi.post(
                "/data", {
                dataName
            }, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + state.tokenData,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                console.log(dataEntry.length)
                setDataEntry([...dataEntry, response.data]);
                console.log(dataEntry.length)
                setDataUpdate(true);
            })


        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.response.data);
        }
    }



    return [getAllData, createData, dataEntry, lastPage, nextPageNumber, dataUpdate];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are updating the state `dataEntry` based on previous state, pass a callback function to `setDataEntry`. Also make sure to spread `prev` state and merge the response result.

**getAllData function**

```js
...
setDataEntry(prev => [...prev, ...response.data.result]);
...
```

**createData function**

```js
...
setDataEntry(prev => [...prev, ...response.data]);
...
```

Also, in `createData` function, the `console.log(dataEntry.length)` won't print latest result as the state updates are async.

Comment: I did try to provide a callback function but still it did not update. Also in createData function the post returns a single object and not an array. So here is how the code looks like
```setDataEntry(prev => [...prev, response.data]);```. But if i just update the state with the returned object the state value gets updated for eg : ```setDataEntry([response.data]);``` wipes the array and adds one element to it. So kinda confused why adding an element to array does not work.

Comment: state updates are asynchronous , so you wont be able to update the state and immediately print the state ... also how are you calling these functions (createData and getAllData)?

Comment: ```import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
const Data = () => {
//custom hook
    const [getData, createData] = useData();
    const [dataName, setDataName] = useState('');
   useEffect(() => {getData(0, 10);  }, [])
   const addData = () => {createData({ dataName }); }
return (
        <View>
  <Input
onChangeText={setDataName} keyboardType='default' />
            <Button
                                    title="Add"
                                    onPress={addData}
                                />
        </View>
    )
}

export default Data;```